# How to change ticks on a histogram? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a histogram with only a few values. As a result, the x axis ticks are decimals:

[image]

How can I make it 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: you probably also want to specify the binning explicitly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) to set the locations of the x-axis tick marks.

Without the code used to generate the question's histogram, I resorted to creating data to produce a similar histogram. In this first example, we have a histogram with the default tick marks.

```
from pylab import hist, show

x = [1.1]*29 + [2]*7 + [3.2]*3 + [5]
hist(x)
show()
```

[image: Histogram with default tick marks.]

The objective is to have tick marks at 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and the next example does this by using `xticks`.

```
from pylab import hist, show, xticks

x = [1.1]*29 + [2]*7 + [3.2]*3 + [5]
hist(x)
xticks(range(1, 6))
show()
```

[image: Histogram with modified tick marks.]